# Problema de optimización con fmincon

Tags: optimización, matlab, matrices, programación-funcional

Buenas tardes,

## Introducción

Necesito resolver el siguiente problema de optimización, [cuya descripción teórica puede encontrarse en las secciones 7.7.1 y 7.7.2 de este enlace.](http://read.pudn.com/downloads144/ebook/626798/Differential%20Evolution_A%20Practical%20Approach%20to%20Global%20Optimization.pdf)

#### Definición de fmincon y de la función objetivo

```
function [v] = LP_Irr_LDPC(N,Ebn0)

options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxIter', 10000, 'MaxFunEvals', 10000, 'StepTolerance', 1e-100);
fun = @(v) -sum(v(1:N)./(1:N));

A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [0, ones(1,N-1)];
beq = 1;
lb = zeros(1,N);
ub = [0, ones(1,N-1)];
nonlcon = @(v)DensEv_BEC(v,Ebn0);
l0 = [0 rand(1,N-1)];
l0 = round(l0./sum(l0),2);

v = fmincon(fun,l0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);
end
```

#### Restricciones

```
function [c, ceq] = DensEv_BEC(v,Ebn0)

% It is also needed to modify this function, as you cannot pass parameters
% from others to it. 

h = [0 rand(1,999)];
h = h./sum(h);

syms x;
X = x.^(0:(length(h)-1));
R = h*transpose(X);

ebn0 = 10^(Ebn0/10);
Rm = 1;
LLR = (-50:50);
p03 = 0.3;
LLR03 = log((1-p03)/p03);
r03 = 1 - p03;
noise03 = (2*r03*Rm*ebn0)^-1;
pf03 = normpdf(LLR, LLR03, noise03);
sumpf03 = sum(pf03(1:length(pf03)/2));

divisions = 200;

Aj = zeros(1, divisions);
rho = zeros(1, divisions);
xj = zeros(1, divisions);
N = 2000; % Length(v) -> Same value as in 'Complete.m'

for j=1:1:divisions
    xj(j) = sumpf03*j/divisions;
    rho(j) = subs(R,x,1-xj(j));
    Aj(j) = 1 - rho(j);
end

c = zeros(1, length(xj));
lambda = zeros(1, length(Aj));
for j = 1:1:length(xj)
    lambda(j) = sum(v(2:N).*(Aj(j).^(1:(N-1))));
    c(j) = sumpf03*lambda(j) - xj(j);
end

save Almacen
%ceq = [];
ceq = sum(v)-1;
end
```

#### Función principal

El resultado del problema de optimización anterior ha de utilizarse dentro del siguiente script. Sin embargo, como el problema de optimización no consigue converger a ningún valor que satisfaga todas las condiciones (concretamente, que la suma de elementos de v sea igual a la unidad) la función MacKayNeal.m da error. Podéis encontrar más información sobre el funcionamiento de esta función en el siguiente enlace dentro de esta misma página, [donde pregunto otra cuestión sin resolver al respecto:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52535/problema-de-optimizaci%C3%B3n-con-funci%C3%B3n-fmincon-y-algoritmo-mackay-neal)

```
clear;clc

N = 2000;
r = 0.5;
%EbN0 = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12]; % EbN0 in dB
EbN0 = 1;
iterations = 15; % Número de iteraciones del codificador (suave)
frames = 5; % Number of frames (N bits per frame)

for i = 1:length(EbN0)
    % LP - Distribuciones de bits por filas y por columnas
    v = LP_Irr_LDPC(N,EbN0(i));
    load('Almacen.mat');
    % DE - Distribuciones de bits por filas y por columnas
    %[v_DE h_DE]

    % LP - Determinación de las matrices generadora y de paridad
    H_LP = MacKayNeal(N,r,v,h);
    G_LP = GaussElm(H_LP,N,N*r);
    % DE - Determinación de las matrices generadora y de paridad
    %H_DE = MacKayNeal(N,r,v_DE,h_DE);
    %G_DE = GaussElm(H_DE,N,N*r);

    BER_LP(i) = 0;
    %BER_DE(i) = 0;
    for j = 1:frames
        % Encoding message
        u = transpose(round(rand(N*r,1)));       
        tx_LP = u*G_LP;
        %TX_DE = u*G_DE;

        % BPSK modulation
        bpskMod_LP = 2*tx_LP - 1;
        %bpskMod_DE = 2*tx_DE - 1;

        % Addition of AWGN
        N0 = 1/(10^(EbN0(i)/10));
        rx_LP = bpskMod_LP + sqrt(N0/2)*randn(size(bpskMod_LP));
        %rx_DE = bpskMod_DE + sqrt(N0/2)*randn(size(bpskMod_DE));

        % Decoding
        vhat_LP = decodeLogDomain(rx_LP, H_LP, N0, iterations); % Hay que hacer ésto
        %vhat_DE = decodeLogDomain(rx_DE, H_DE, N0, iterations);

        % Get BER
        [num_LP, rat_LP] = biterr(vhat_LP, tx_LP);
        BER_LP(i) = BER_LP(i)+rat_LP;
        %[num_DE, rat_DE] = biterr(vhat_DE, tx_DE);
        %BER_DE(i) = BER_DE(i)+rat_DE;
    end

    % Get average of BER
    BER_LP(i) = BER_LP(i)/frames;
    %BER_DE(i) = BER_DE(i)/frames;
end

% Plot the result
semilogy(EbN0, BER_LP, 'o-');
grid on; hold on;
%semilogy(EbN0, BER_DE, 'x-');
%grid on; hold off;
```

Comment: Os recomendaría que utilizaseis los siguientes parámetros para que la función converja (fracase) más rápido:

En el primer bloque de código, eliminar el parámetro StepTolerance y reducir y/o eliminar los de MaxIter y MaxFunEvals.

En el segundo, cambiar el valor de N a 100 y el de h a [0 rand(1,49)].

En el tercero, cambiar el valor de N a 100.